# ByteCodeLink error with GHCi and C file

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

When I run my file using a foreign import for a C function I made, I get this error.

```
    ByteCodeLink: can't find label
    During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
              richards
    This may be due to you not asking GHCi to load extra object files,
    archives or DLLs needed by your current session.  Restart GHCi, specifying
    the missing library using the -L/path/to/object/dir and -lmissinglibname
    flags, or simply by naming the relevant files on the GHCi command line.
    Alternatively, this link failure might indicate a bug in GHCi.
    If you suspect the latter, please send a bug report to:
     glasgow-haskell-bugs@haskell.org
```

After creating a .cabal file and loading it in GHCi from there, I still get this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly do you invoke `ghci`?  Usually this error means that you need to pass the object code for that function to `ghci` like: `ghci HaskellCode.hs CCode.o` or something like that.

Comment: I invoke ghci as normal then import the package which I have installed using Cabal. Otherwise I just invoke it as ghci HaskellCode.hs

Comment: First try manually loading the object file in ghci by passing both the Haskell module and the compiled `*.o` file as command line arguments.  Also, you should provide much more detailed information, like the contents of your cabal file and your project layout.